# I can't link library with CMake

Tags: cmake, firebreath

I used firebreath to make npAPI Plugin.

My Code uses **giblib**, so I add this code in CMakeLists.txt

```
find_library(TESTLIB_LIBRARY2 giblib)
include_directories(${TESTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(UbuntuCaptureTest TESTLIB_LIBRARY2)
```

I'm a newbie about cmake

so I studied some tutorial about CMake and some resource in firebreath homepage.

(http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Using+Libraries)

I think I repeat all steps. So I can't understand why it doesn't work.

This is result for finding files.

```
xxxx@xxxx-VirtualBox:~/test$ sudo find / -name *giblib*

/usr/bin/giblib-config
/usr/share/man/man1/giblib-config.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/giblib1
/usr/share/doc/giblib-dev
/usr/include/giblib
/usr/include/giblib/giblib.h
/usr/include/giblib/giblib_config.h
/usr/lib/libgiblib.so
/usr/lib/libgiblib.so.1
/usr/lib/libgiblib.a
/usr/lib/libgiblib.so.1.0.6
/usr/lib/libgiblib.la
/var/lib/dpkg/info/giblib1.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/giblib1.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/giblib1.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/giblib-dev.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/giblib-dev.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/giblib1.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/giblib1.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/giblib1.list
/var/cache/apt/archives/giblib1_1.2.4-5ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/giblib-dev_1.2.4-5ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

Comment: Without more specifics about what "doesn't work" means, it's difficult to say what issues you may be having, other than the one that antonakos pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't link to a library named `TESTLIB_LIBRARY2` but link to the value of the variable of that name:

```
target_link_libraries(UbuntuCaptureTest ${TESTLIB_LIBRARY2})
```

Comment: After repeat your solution, This error messages appear.

UbuntuCaptureTestAPI.cpp:(.text+0xa8b): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'

UbuntuCaptureTestAPI.cpp:(.text+0xae6): undefined reference to `XScreenNumberOfScreen'

...

UbuntuCaptureTestAPI.cpp:(.text+0xba4): undefined reference to `imlib_context_set_visual'

Comment: @도현우 That error doesn't mean that my answer is wrong. It means that you have to link to even more libraries for your code to build. Googling the identifiers might help you to find out which.